# Deploy .Net Core Console App to Raspberry PI and Remote Debug

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-10-iot-core

I've written a basic console app in C# using .Net Core 1.1 and Visual Studio 2017 Community. The app runs fine on my machine and am ready to deploy it to a Raspberry Pi 3 running Windows 10 IoT v.10.0.15063.0, which is running on the same network and visible in the IoT Dashboard.

All of the tutorials I've seen online indicate that I should be able to select a remote machine as the debug target from the drop-down on the start debugging button, as shown here:

[image: drop-down]

Unfortunately for me, all I get in this drop-down is the project name:

[image: my drop-down]

My project's debug properties are as follows:

[image]

There are plenty of articles online describing how to do this for a UWP application, but I've found nothing for a .Net Core app.

Is my only viable option to re-write my app as a UWP Background App (this raises a whole host of other questions), or is there a way I can deploy and debug my .Net core app?

Comment: right click on project and click on _Properties_ then go _Debug_ tab and check _Start options_ , can you see the Target device?

Comment: Start options is not available as an option in the Debug properties. I've added a screenshot to the post to demonstrate what I've got.

Answer (score -1):

When you installed your Visual Studio 2017 Community the **remote tools** option does not contain the installed package, now you can ***download the remote tools for visual studio 2017*** for and the remote debugging is enabled on your machine.
follow the below link and download that.

[Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#remote-tools-for-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: So I've installed the Remote Tools on my dev machine, but the drop-down remains the same - no options for Remote Machine